# How to not apply styling to a table element

Tags: html, css

I have the following styling in a css file that is applied to a table. Now I have a second table, and I do not want the second table to have this specific styling. How do I prevent my second table from getting this styling?

Here is the css:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

tr > i:nth-child(even), tr > i:nth-child(odd) {
 background: transparent;
 
}
 tr:nth-child(odd),  {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table id="firstTable" class="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="secondTable" class="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"#firstTable" will indicate your browser to apply this css only on table with id="firstTable"

```css
#firstTable tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #f6f6f6;
}

#firstTable tr > i:nth-child(even), tr > i:nth-child(odd) {
background: transparent;

}
#firstTable tr:nth-child(odd),  {
background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table id="firstTable" class="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="secondTable" class="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is just assign class names to your selectors

```css
.firstTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.firstTable tr > i:nth-child(even), .firstTable tr > i:nth-child(odd) {
 background: transparent;
 
}
 .firstTable tr:nth-child(odd),  {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table id="firstTable" class="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="secondTable" class="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one element **NOT** using the style, try [`:not` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_not.asp) in CSS3.

In your case, `table:not(.secondTable)` will fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a css for the html class element, I mean You should change the css file, and specify the css element for classes.